# How to connect integrate mysql to other post relational DATA?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, odbc

Is there any way that we can connect MySql DB to one of Post Relational DB or in simpler words  if we create a application totally on MySQL so we want some fields to be sent or transported using some bridge  to the other DB which is post relational (INTERSYSTEM's CACHE DB) we are using odbc to perform this function but to save our application integrity and environment can we use something like web services?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd want to use SOAP or similar to expose the machines to one another securely and call methods on one another.

The XML can seam quite heavy, but it's standardised at least.

Some useful pages/notes:
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/
- http://phpmaster.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/
- PHP's SoapClient has some unfortunate parts that can be a pain when you're writing code compositionally
- SOAP on .NET machines has some very annoying foibles that require (for instance) manually replacing strings in your requests (which can be done in SoapClient's __doRequest function that you'll need to overload) = Hopefully this will never be relevant for you